# Angular 16 monorepo with nest.js faisl to build

Tags: angular

I started a boilerplate angular project in a mono repo configuration with nest.js.

To install dependencies run: `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`

This error is my main concern:

```
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
```

Errors:

```
➜  geo-cast git:(main) cd ui
➜  ui git:(main) 
➜  ui git:(main) npm run start

> ui@0.0.0 start
> ng serve

✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files   | Names         |  Raw Size
vendor.js             | vendor        |   5.09 MB | 
polyfills.js          | polyfills     | 329.56 kB | 
styles.css, styles.js | styles        | 227.65 kB | 
main.js               | main          | 173.21 kB | 
runtime.js            | runtime       |   6.96 kB | 

                      | Initial Total |   5.81 MB

Build at: 2023-05-26T04:13:46.196Z - Hash: d9869875966d2349 - Time: 15034ms

../node_modules/jwt-fsm/dist/index.js:10:47-54 - Warning: Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

../node_modules/jwt-fsm/dist/index.js:13:44-51 - Warning: Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

Warning: /home/hesamian/workspace/geo-cast/ui/src/app/app.module.ts depends on 'store'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: /home/hesamian/workspace/geo-cast/ui/src/app/utilities/route.utility.ts depends on '@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies



../node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/delete-output-dir.js:45:24-37 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/hesamian/workspace/geo-cast/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils'

../node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/delete-output-dir.js:46:15-30 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/hesamian/workspace/geo-cast/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

../node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/normalize-asset-patterns.js:46:13-26 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/hesamian/workspace/geo-cast/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils'

../node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/normalize-asset-patterns.js:47:26-41 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/hesamian/workspace/geo-cast/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

../node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/normalize-cache.js:15:15-30 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/hesamian/workspace/geo-cast/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

../node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/normalize-file-replacements.js:46:13-26 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/hesamian/workspace/geo-cast/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils'

../node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/normalize-file-replacements.js:47:26-41 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/hesamian/workspace/geo-cast/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

../node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/normalize-polyfills.js:14:13-26 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/hesamian/workspace/geo-cast/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils'

../node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/normalize-polyfills.js:15:15-30 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/hesamian/workspace/geo-cast/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

../node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/run-module-as-observable-fork.js:14:24-48 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/hesamian/workspace/geo-cast/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils'

../node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/run-module-as-observable-fork.js:15:15-30 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/hesamian/workspace/geo-cast/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

../node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/json/schema/registry.js:53:26-41 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/hesamian/workspace/geo-cast/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/json/schema'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
        - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "http": false }

../node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/json/schema/registry.js:54:27-43 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/home/hesamian/workspace/geo-cast/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/json/schema'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
        - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "https": false }

../node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/json/schema/registry.js:56:25-39 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in '/home/hesamian/workspace/geo-cast/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/json/schema'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
        - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "url": false }

../node_modules/source-map/lib/read-wasm.js:22:13-26 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/hesamian/workspace/geo-cast/node_modules/source-map/lib'

../node_modules/source-map/lib/read-wasm.js:23:15-30 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/hesamian/workspace/geo-cast/node_modules/source-map/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

../node_modules/tree-kill/index.js:3:19-43 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/hesamian/workspace/geo-cast/node_modules/tree-kill'

node:util - Error: Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:util" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.

Error: ../node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/core/src/host.d.ts:42:247 - error TS2694: Namespace 'ts' has no exported member 'ResolutionMode'.

42     resolveTypeReferenceDirectives: ((typeReferenceDirectiveNames: string[] | readonly ts.FileReference[], containingFile: string, redirectedReference: ts.ResolvedProjectReference | undefined, options: ts.CompilerOptions, containingFileMode?: ts.ResolutionMode) => (ts.ResolvedTypeReferenceDirective | undefined)[]) | undefined;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: ../node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/program_driver/src/ts_create_program_driver.d.ts:37:247 - error TS2694: Namespace 'ts' has no exported member 'ResolutionMode'.

37     resolveTypeReferenceDirectives: ((typeReferenceDirectiveNames: string[] | readonly ts.FileReference[], containingFile: string, redirectedReference: ts.ResolvedProjectReference | undefined, options: ts.CompilerOptions, containingFileMode?: ts.ResolutionMode) => (ts.ResolvedTypeReferenceDirective | undefined)[]) | undefined;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/app.module.ts:33:24 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'store'. '/home/hesamian/workspace/geo-cast/node_modules/store/dist/store.legacy.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/store` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'store';`

33 import * as store from 'store';
                          ~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/app.module.ts:42:12 - error NG6002: 'LoggerModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.

 42   imports: [
               ~
 43     BrowserModule,
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
... 
 61     LoggerModule.forRoot({ level: NgxLoggerLevel.DEBUG, serverLogLevel: NgxLoggerLevel.ERROR })
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 62   ],
    ~~~

  ../node_modules/ngx-logger/lib/logger.module.d.ts:3:22
    3 export declare class LoggerModule {
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This likely means that the library (ngx-logger) which declares LoggerModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.


Error: src/app/app.module.ts:42:12 - error NG6002: 'LoggerModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.

 42   imports: [
               ~
 43     BrowserModule,
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
... 
 61     LoggerModule.forRoot({ level: NgxLoggerLevel.DEBUG, serverLogLevel: NgxLoggerLevel.ERROR })
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 62   ],
    ~~~

  ../node_modules/ngx-logger/lib/logger.module.d.ts:3:22
    3 export declare class LoggerModule {
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This likely means that the library (ngx-logger) which declares LoggerModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.


Error: src/app/app.module.ts:52:5 - error NG6002: This import contains errors, which may affect components that depend on this NgModule.

52     CommonComponentModule,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/modules/common.module.ts:25:5 - error NG6002: 'LoadingBarHttpClientModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.

25     LoadingBarHttpClientModule,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../node_modules/@ngx-loading-bar/http-client/http.module.d.ts:1:22
    1 export declare class LoadingBarHttpClientModule {
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This likely means that the library (@ngx-loading-bar/http-client) which declares LoadingBarHttpClientModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.


Error: src/app/modules/common.module.ts:27:5 - error NG6002: 'LoadingBarModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.

27     LoadingBarModule,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../node_modules/@ngx-loading-bar/core/core.module.d.ts:1:22
    1 export declare class LoadingBarModule {
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This likely means that the library (@ngx-loading-bar/core) which declares LoadingBarModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.


Error: src/app/modules/common.module.ts:29:5 - error NG6002: 'LoadingBarRouterModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.

29     LoadingBarRouterModule,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../node_modules/@ngx-loading-bar/router/router.module.d.ts:3:22
    3 export declare class LoadingBarRouterModule {
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This likely means that the library (@ngx-loading-bar/router) which declares LoadingBarRouterModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.




** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


✖ Failed to compile.
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@root/lib": "*",
    "@angular/animations": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0",
    "@iplab/ngx-file-upload": "^16.0.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/http-client": "^4.2.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/router": "^4.2.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "jwt-fsm": "^1.0.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^10.2.0",
    "ngx-logger": "^4.1.1",
    "store": "^2.0.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~5.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.2",
    "eslint": "^8.39.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^34.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1"
  }
}
```

[repository](https://github.com/amir734jj/geo-cast/tree/d0a2a02c945f5fe05d7b4fa2e4dc3aea25553af6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the package:

> npm i node-polyfill-webpack-plugin

And add the following to your `webpack.config.js`

```js
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
    // Other rules...
    plugins: [
        new NodePolyfillPlugin()
    ]
}
```

**EDIT:**

Install [@angular-builders/custom-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) and follow the usages guide, and if you haven't created `webpack.config.js` with the content above then do so.

Comment: Angular doesn't have webpack.config